# Ajax after onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a textarea that trigger an ajax request onchange.
The point is that I'm worried about queueing too many requests to the server, because that request is going to save content of this textarea in a db.
Actually my idea was something about creating a sort of timer, which, after a couple of seconds after the last onchange, start the ajax request to save the textarea data.
The point is that I don't have any clue if it's a good idea, and also, I still don't figure out a code to write down.
I'm using JQuery.

Comment: Using a timer is a very good idea - look into using setTimeout and clearTimeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing off of [Dave's code above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568926/ajax-after-onchange/23568989#23568989)

You can throttle the calls, basic idea would be to check to see if there is a timer

```
var requestTimer;
$('#textarea').on('change', function() {
   if (requestTimer) window.clearTimeout(requestTimer);  //see if there is a timeout that is active, if there is remove it.
   requestTimer = setTimeout(submitFormAjax, 1000);  //delay before making the call
});
```

You could also check to see if there is an Ajax request that is active.

```
var requestTimer;
var xhr;
$('#textarea').on('change', function() {
   if (requestTimer) window.clearTimeout(requestTimer);  //see if there is a timeout that is active, if there is remove it.
   if (xhr) xhr.abort();  //kill active Ajax request
   requestTimer = setTimeout(submitFormAjax, 1000);  //delay before making the call
});


function submitFormAjax() {
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:$('#textarea').val(),
        success:function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This one is actually what i was looking for. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Try as below, reduce the number of calls by delaying the ajax call for a few seconds to see if the user is going to keep typing

```
var timeoutId; 
$('#textarea').on('change', function() {
  if(timeoutId){ 
    // prevent last timeout from sending the ajax call
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = 0;
  }
  timeoutId =setTimeout(submitFormAjax, 200);
   return false;
});
function submitFormAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:$('#textarea').val(),
        success:function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to "cancel" the previous setTimeout before creating a new one?

Comment: Might want a longer timeout than 200ms... that's probably around as quick as normal typing! Also this doesn't use clearTimeout to cancel the scheduled post when another key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Good or bad idea: is entirely up to you, your server's proximity, server resources and number of users keying in the text :) Anyways, the code for timer is something like as follows:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

var textTimeout = null;
$( "#textarea" ).on( "keyup", function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    cancelTimeout( textTimeout );
    textTimeout = setTimeout( function() {
        $.post("www.example.com", { data: $that.val() }, function() {
            alert( "Posted all text!" );
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

However, if you use the "change" event in jQuery, then it happens only when you **lose focus** on the textarea, so you don't need to worry about requests queueing up (yey!).